# Scala pass function as parameter to another function

Tags: scala, function-parameter

Sorry about this mess. I'm still getting my way in scala. Rephrasing the all question is this:

```
def func1(x: Double, y: Double) = {
  x+y
}

def func2(x: Double, y: Double) = {
  x-y
}

def calc(f: (Double, Double) => Double, z: Int) = {
  f(1,2) + z
}

//Sometimes I want to call
calc(func1(1,2), 3)

//Other times
calc(func2(1,2), 3)
```

and I get this error:

```
<console>:52: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: (Double, Double) => Double
              calc(func1(1,2), 3)
                        ^
```

what is the proper way to call calc()?

thanks

Comment: This is not passing a function as parameter but rather passing the result of a function.

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the arguments to `f()`, i.e. the `1` and the `2`, are supplied in the body of `calc()`.

```
def calc(f: (Double, Double) => Double, z: Int) = {
  f(1,2) + z
}
```

Therefore you don't need to specify any arguments for the functions being passed in.

```
calc(func1, 3)
calc(func2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're using a var(don't wanna go in detail read [this](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#23-should-not-update-a-var-using-loops-or-conditions) for more info), which isn't considered a good practice, if your Map is mean to be used locally within the class you can create a Mutable Map.

Coming back to your question:
If you want your function to work as expected then you should make sure that **doSomeComputation** function returns the values which is expected by **otherFunction** as input param, something like this

```
def doSomeComputation(m1: Map[String, List[(String, Double)]], name: String) = {
      (Map("some_key" -> List(("tuple1",1.0))), "tuple2")
}
```

return type is **(Map[String, List[String,Int]], String)**

However it doesn't make much sense of what you're trying to do, I can help you to understand if you can clearly mention what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass the function signature `f: (Map[String,List[(String, Double)]], String) => Double` rather than just the return type.  A trivialized example below:

```
var testMap: Map[String, List[(String, Double)]] = Map(
  "First" -> List(("a", 1.0), ("b", 2.0)),
  "Second" -> List(("c", 3.0), ("d", 4.0))
)
// testMap: Map[String,List[(String, Double)]] = Map(First -> List((a,1.0), (b,2.0)), Second -> List((c,3.0), (d,4.0)))

def doSomeComputation(m1: Map[String, List[(String, Double)]], name: String): Double = {
  m1.getOrElse(name, List[(String, Double)]()).map( x => x._2 ).max
}
// doSomeComputation: (m1: Map[String,List[(String, Double)]], name: String)Double

def doSomeOtherComputation(m1: Map[String, List[(String, Double)]], name: String): Double = {
  m1.getOrElse(name, List[(String, Double)]()).map( x => x._2 ).min
}
// doSomeOtherComputation: (m1: Map[String,List[(String, Double)]], name: String)Double

def otherFunction(f: (Map[String, List[(String, Double)]], String) => Double, otherName: String) = {
  f(testMap, "First") * otherName.length
}
// otherFunction: (f: (Map[String,List[(String, Double)]], String) => Double, otherName: String)Double

println(otherFunction(doSomeComputation, "computeOne"))
// 20.0

println(otherFunction(doSomeOtherComputation, "computeOne"))
// 10.0
```

Depending on your use case, it might be a good idea to pass also `testMap` and `name` as parameters to `otherFunction`.